# Communication between BDI agents

Tags: service, communication, agents

i am facing a problem with understanding the platform awareness concept. My aim now is to make 2 agents communicate (one agent is on my laptop and the other one is on my raspberry pi) and my laptop & pi are connected to the same wifi network. The agent on my laptop provides a service that is required by the agent on the pi. I am facing a problem with the binding and scope arguments.

Hope anyone can help me
Regards, 
Sandra

Comment: which plataform is being used? you need to provide better description of your system and the problem.

Comment: I am using Jadex tool to bulid my agents.I have already fixed the platform awareness issue but now i am facing another problem. Currently i am using java and eclipse to build my agents. However the problem is in the agent that requires the service. When i add both agents in the same project, everything works fine. However when i run one agent (provider) on my raspberry after i export it as a runnble java file, the the other agent on my laptop (the user that requires the service) has the following error: ITranslationService (marked in bold) can't be resolved to a type.

Comment: This is probably because the agent providing the service is not in the same project.
@RequiredServices(@RequiredService(name="transser", type=ITranslationService.class,
multiple=true, binding=@Binding(dynamic=true, scope=Binding.SCOPE_GLOBAL)))
I would really appreciate your help in this issue as urgently need to start with my actual bachelor project.
This is only a trial example and i am really behind
Regards,
Sandra

Comment: Looks like library issues in run-time. If you need all this working urgently, you should consider hiring some consultant. If you have further problems, you can post new well-written questions and set some bounty. Nevertheless, you can change your bachelor project for an easier one, suitable to your knowledge, needs and urgency.